# Can a language have both nominative/accusative and ergative/absolutive syntactic systems in its syntactic structure?

Tags: syntax, morphology, morphosyntax, ergativity

These examples are from Kui, a Trans New Guinean language spoken on Alor island, Indonesia.

```
(1)  nya      yai   umasingin  u=ga=sam               u=ga=bur=i.
     1pl.Sub  v.    n.         appl=3sg.obj.Caus=adj  appl=3sg.obj.Caus=adj=perf
     we       come  mosque     it.make=soft           it.make=flat=already
     'We come to repair the mosque.'

(2)  na        er     u=sanam=i.
     1sg.Subj  n      Caus=adj=perf
     I         water  make.hot.already
     'I already heated the water.'
```

Prefix *u-* at the first sentence functions as an applicative marker but at the 2nd sentence, it behaves as an causative. Is it possible ?

Comment: Where is the Kui data from?

Comment: From my own research... I live in Kupang, Indonesia..

Comment: What do applicative and causative markers have to do with nom/acc erg/abs systems? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Let me say that it is really good to see someone on here discussing original research instead of pasting stuff off Wikipedia. A very rare treat.
From your examples I do not really see the function of u-. I think we need more material.

Comment: Split ergative languages are more common than "pure" ergatives. Hindi has an ergative structure in the perfect tense; many Australian languages have an ergative-absolutive case system for nouns and an accusative-nominative case system for pronouns. And even English has some [constructions that use ergative semantics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/ergativity.pdf) (though not case-marking, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Sticking to the question of the title, yes, some languages exhibit clearly both a nominative-accusative syntactic systems and an ergative-absolutive system. A famous example of such a language is [Warlpiri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlpiri_language), in which agreement follows a nominative-accusative pattern and case marking follows an ergative-absolutive system. References for this, and more generally the syntax of split ergativity, can be found (among many other sources) in the works of [Julie Anne Legate](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~jlegate/).

Comment: I believe Basque has also mostly absolutive-ergative structure but in the past tense it goes to nominative-accusative one.